# Unpacking a tuple of lists into two lists

Tags: python, list, return

I have a function which returns a tuple of two lists ( E.G `return (["a", "b"], ["c"])` ).

I'm trying to append the two returned lists into two different lists.
I could do something like:

```
temp1, temp2 = functionCall()

list1.append(temp1)
list2.append(temp2)
```

But I'm trying to find some more elegant solution without temporary variables.
Some things I tried are using for loops and lambdas but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

I'm probably missing something obvious since I'm pretty inexperienced.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You can simply do `list1.append(functionCall()[0])` and `list2.append(functionCall()[1])` since your func is already returning a tuple.

Comment: Then you'de have to call the function twice

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 yes but to bypass the temp variable this is the simplest way, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: i don't think it can be simpler. python is simple but not necessarily simplistic.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with temp variables?

Comment: Exactly. Which is a problem since It creates some joints and controllers ( It's part of an autorig script for Maya) and then returns their names.

Comment: @Mr.T I just really dislike them in an aesthetic way. I'm using them for now but I was searching for a different solution.

Comment: I believe there are tons of way to make this more complicated, but to use temp variables is definitely the recommended way

Comment: @Animamorta And because you are aesthetically displeased, you rather call a function twice? Ooookeh.

Comment: `[[list1,list2][c]+[e] for c,e in enumerate(functionCall())]`. Eliminates calling the function twice

Comment: @MrT: Actually, the comment about it being a problem is a response to Idlehands and that I can't use two function calls. And since, like I said, I'm using them for now I can't understand why you would think I'd prefer to call the function twice or where would you deduct that from.

Comment: @Animamorta you are unnecessarily creating not-a-problem by unnecessarily complicating things. you already have the power of unpacking assignment already. what you are asking for is something called bifunctor, which roughly allows you to perform two actions separately. if you are chasing for those type of aesthetics, you should program in functional languages.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr I understand that and in fact, I'm not disregarding the obvious solution but currently using it and have the intention of using it if I don't find something satisfying. This doesn't mean that I shouldn't be trying to find a different solution to a type of code which piqued my curiosity. By the way, I really like functional languages but they aren't supported by Maya for what I know.

Comment: OK, the basic answer is that there's no simple shorthand for this. There are ways to avoid the variable, but they'll be more complicated and confusing, like @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000's comment.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr Reading my response again makes me think it may sound aggressive. If that is the case I ask forgiveness since it wasn't my Intention.

Comment: @Animamorta why it bothers you to use temp vars in the first place? to settle this question, the goal should be fix this misunderstanding.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I'm not really sure. I just always found them displeasing to my eyes. It's really just that. For how stupid it is I prefer a long code a bit more unreadable than to use them when I work on my personal projects ( Even though I just use them when I write for other people ).

Comment: that is not rare and is the most highly destructive idea i've ever met in my software career. with this understanding, the produced code tends to be harder to understand, error prone and consequently very hard to trace issues. i highly recommend you to fix that for the sake of helping others and being a good team player.

Comment: @HuStmpHrr I don't completely agree with you since I only keep it to my personal ( and this means only read/used by me ) projects. But I totally agree from a team perspective and understand that It's probably true that I should just try and pass over this (non)-issue I have with temp variables. Thank you for the advices

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible to change the function signature and send in the top level lists as arguments and retrieve the final appended lists out directly?
Something like:

```
functionCall(list1, list2)
```

Comment: in this case assignment to the left becomes unnecessary. however, it's arguable that in python, if it's a good idea to modify the parameters of a function.

Comment: It would only become unnecessary if they were globals.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 The assignments are unnecessary because the function can modify the lists in place.

Answer (score 0):

edit: explain and format

This += with list1 is actually a function call to extend for you

```
list1 += functionCall()

list2.append(list1.pop())
```

Comment: You may want to format your code and describe your answer a bit